# Is there anyway to us a variable name like a control name

Tags: vba, variables, controls

I might be making this harder than it really is but... Say like I have two Userforms, on of the forms has 10 textboxes I would like the values for and have it pop up a message for each one. So I can use:

```
For i=0 to 10
    MsgBox UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & i).Text
Next i
```

Now lets say I want to to transfer each of those into Variables labeled TB1 - TB10 and I want to pass the value of each text box to the variables.

Instead of doing it one by one is there a way to do it like the above statement? Anything like:

```
UserForm2.Variables("TB" & i)?
```

UPDATED:
This is what my code looks like:

```
For z = 1 To 25

   If Module1.FL(z) <> "" Then 

      For pCopy = 1 To UBound(PL1)

        FileCopy PL1(pCopy), ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\DB\Img\" & result &    TextBox1.Text & TextBox8.Text & TextBox10.Text & "\Car\" & Module1.FL(z) & "\" & pCopy & ".gdb"
        PL1(pCopy) = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\DB\Img\" & result & TextBox1.Text & TextBox8.Text & TextBox10.Text & "\Car\" & Module1.FL(z) & "\" & pCopy & ".gdb"

      Next pCopy

   End If
Next z
```

It checks a set of array of names it the Module. If it finds a name it will copy file names stored in PL1. Thing is, PL1 is only specific to a certain set of files. I have PL1=PL25 that I need it to check to see if there is any data in them and if so copy the contents to a specific name from the Module. So I need something like PL(z).

Answer (score 0):

From Help

> **Controls Collection**
>
> Includes all the controls contained in an object.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> Each control in the Controls collection of an object has a unique index whose value can be either an integer or a string. The index value for the first control in a collection is 0; the value for the second control is 1, and so on. This value indicates the order in which controls were added to the collection.
>
> If the index is a string, it represents the name of the control. The Name property of a control also specifies a control's name.
>
> You can use the Controls collection to enumerate or count individual controls, and to set their properties. For example, you can enumerate the Controls collection of a particular form and set the Height property of each control to a specified value.
>
> **Note**   The For Each...Next statement is useful for enumerating a collection.